# How to find total numbers of people with height higher than some value?

Tags: statistics

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4mgR.gif]

Is a continuous distribution. The y axis is not probability, how do I find how many people with height higher than some value?

[image: http://www.dogstuff.info/multiple_gene_traits_kral_files/image002.gif]

Now assume it is an even distribution. y is no. of people, x is height. The highest person is 2m. 
$y=1$ and $0\leq x\leq 2$

how to find total numbers of people with height higher than 1m?
y=1 is continuous, for every x, it is 1, means there is 1 person having height x m. Between 1 and 2, there are infinite points, than there is infinite people? It doesn't make sense..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest t this:

As you note, continuous distributions on finite or even countably-infinite populations are just idealizations/extensions of discrete distributions.

So, given you know the size of the population, choosing a height $h$, find the
percentile associated with the value $h$. This tells you the percentage of people smaller than $h$. You can find the percentile of $h$ by , e.g., integrating the pdf. from the lowest value up to $h$.

Once you know the percentile $p_h$ , multiply $100-p_h$ by the size of the population, and you have your amount.

Comment: Thank you. If the distribution is $-(x-1)^2+1$ now, than the amount is $$\frac{\int_{0}^{h} (-(x-1)^2+1) dx}{\int_{0}^{2} (-(x-1)^2+1) dx}*size of the population$$ ? @Gary.

Comment: @fairytale: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @fairytale: Let me correct myself. if you want to find the proportion that is taller, you need to subtract that ratio from 1, and then multiply by the size of the population. Your formula gives you the proportion of people _smaller_ than $h$. If you subtract this ratio from $1$, then multiply by the size of the population, you will get the amount taller than $h$.